# AudioConfig: AVPlayer vs. Gracenote

Tags: objective-c, ios6, gracenote

My application recognizes music, using the Gracenote SDK. After recognising has finished, a new view is  shown which offers an AVPlayer to listen to the iTunes preview of the song. Works fine so far.

After poping the player view of the stack, the Gracenote recognition is broken. I get the following error in the console:

`<com.apple.main-thread> AURemoteIO::Initialize failed: -10851 (enable 1, outf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, non-inter> inf< 1 ch,  44100 Hz, Int16>)`

I can't manage to reinitialize the Gracenote controller sucessfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that you might have forgotten some pieces when you integrated our SDK in your app...

You have to double check, eventually use a diff tool to make sure you migrated all the parts.

Make sure you deal with all the events correctly as it's done in the sample. Make sure your project has the same properties than the sample... Etc...

Also make sure depending of what your app is doing that you set the right parameters with the AudioSession. For example like that when you play audio at the same time you are trying a recognition:

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
```